# Apache storm spout is not emitting tuples to all executors of the bolt

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, worker, spout, storm-topology

storm v1.2.2
I have an environment with 6 node cluster each 16 cores. I have deployed a sample topology which reads messages from a kafka topic which has 12 partitions.

**Configurations**

```
Max spout pending is 15.
Topology message timeout is 300 seconds
Topology Acker executor is 2(equal to number of workers).
Worker1 -> 15 executors for Bolt-A (task is equal to number of executors)
Worker2 -> 15 executors for Bolt-A (task is equal to number of executors)
bolts(A to B to C) each has 30 executors across 2 workers
```

I tried to publish 20 messages to that kafka topic, since max spout pending is 15 so only 15 messages should have fetched and emitted from spout but what i figured out was only 7 messages were emitted to Bolt-A. After these 7 messages were emitted to Bolt-B then Bolt-A received remaining messages from spout.

So ideally bolt-A should get 15 messages from spout and once these 15 are acknowledged then remaining 5 messages should have picked up. But i saw only 7 messages were picked up and i could see 8 executors are sitting idle and doing nothing whether i am missing something in storm configuration? I tried with localOrSuffled and Suffled grouping but again few executors are idle always. Any suggestions to equally distribute work to all available executors?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Any solutions that you tried and succeeded?

Comment: @voiddrum - Not yet. Still this mystery exists.